# How to upload file to SFTP over SSH2 with VBA without thirty part applications

Tags: vba, sftp, ssh2

I need a pure VBA solution for uploading files to SFTP over SSH2

I've found that common solution would be to use WINSCP, however environment restricts to use thirty part applications.

I've tried to use FTP way, however it doesn't work.
https://analystcave.com/vba-downloading-files-from-ftp-using-vba/

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in support for SFTP in VBA, Windows, PowerShell or anything readily available.

The closest to built-in SFTP support is an optional Windows 10 OpenSSH component. But that still has to be installed first.

That's why people end up using WinSCP. Note that [WinSCP does not require installation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/portable) (if you use its [scripting interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) and not the .NET/COM library). You can just drop the executable file somewhere along your script.